# Twig include Javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I want to include (yes include) some js file into a big js with Twig but from another directory.

I explain. This is my organisation :

```
AcmeBundle/
    Script/
       blabla1.js
       blabla2.js
    Resources/
       views/
           script.js.twig
```

I want to do two include of blabla1 and blabla2 in the script.js.twig. Something like that :

```
 {% include '@AcmeBundle/Script/blabla1.js' %}
 {% include '@AcmeBundle/Script/blabla2.js' %}
```

But I don't arrive...
And I don't want to put blablas script into Resources.

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance,

Smooba

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

You can just add them in your Assetic javascripts call like usual (or not usual if you are not using it at the moment).

```
{% javascripts
    '@AcmeBundle/Scripts/blabla1.js'
    '@AcmeBundle/Scripts/blabla2.js'
    %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first move/copy your js fiels to assets folder
you can do by this command

```
php app/console assets:install
```

then into your twig file you can include that js like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/AcmeBundle/Script/blabla1.js')}}" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/AcmeBundle/Script/blabla2.js')}}" ></script>
```